# xpath is failing me

Tags: php, xpath

I have an xml structure :

```xml
<Articles>

    <Article ID="111">
        <author>Peter Paul</author>
        <pubDate>01/01/2015</pubDate>  
        <Translations>
            <lang1>English</lang1>
            <lang2>French</lang2>
            <lang3>Arab</lang3>
            <lang3>Chinese</lang3>
        </Translations>
    </Article>

    <Article ID="222">
        <author>Monkey Rice</author>
        <pubDate>01/01/2016</pubDate>  
        <Translations>
            <lang1>English</lang1> 
        </Translations>
    </Article>

    <Article ID="333">
        <author>John Silas</author>
        <pubDate>01/01/2017</pubDate>  
        <Translations>
            <lang1>English</lang1>
            <lang2>French</lang2>
            <lang3>Arab</lang3>
            <lang3>Chinese</lang3>
        </Translations>
    </Article>

</Articles>
```

i created a method AddRecordByInfoMatch() that attempts to
add new node to any  of a given ID anywhere as long 
as a match exists:

```
function AddRecordByInfoMatch($ParentID, $Info_1, $Info_2, $Info_3, array $Record){

            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(blabla.xml);
            $result = $xml->xpath("//*[@ID='$ParentID']");      //get the article ID


            if(!empty($result)){
                foreach($result[0] as $key => $value){

                    $noofChild = count($value);
                    //three info match may lakely be within 3 sub-nodes 
                    if($noofChild >= 3){

                        $query = "//*[node()[contains(text(), \"$Info_1\")] and node()[contains(text(), \"$Info_2\")] and node()[contains(text(), \"$Info_3\")]]";

                        $data = $xml->xpath($query);

                        if(!empty($data[0]){
                                foreach ($Record as $nodname => $val){     
                                    $data[0]->addChild($nodname, $val);   
                                }
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

with ID = 333 in mind, i test-ran it like this :

```
XMLAddRecordByInfoMatch(333, "English", "French", "Chinese", array( 
            "syntax" => irrelevant,
            "adjectives" => None,
            "verbs" => 2,
            "prepositions" => 5 
        ));
```

unfortunately, the output; upon display, added the new record to Article 
with ID 111 to give :

```xml
...
<Article ID="111">
        <author>Peter Paul</author>
        <pubDate>01/01/2015</pubDate>  
        <Translations>
            <lang1>English</lang1>
            <lang2>French</lang2>
            <lang3>Arab</lang3>
            <lang3>Chinese</lang3>

            <syntax>irrelevant</syntax>
            <adjectives>None</adjectives>
            <verbs>2</verbs>
            <prepositions>5</prepositions>

        </Translations>
    </Article>
...
```

and i expected this to be within the Article node of ID 333, which
i specified in the function call. what am i doing wrong in my xpath xpression ?? or how 
can i achieve this ? any help will be highly regarded. Happy new year all.

Comment: `$data = $result->xpath($query);` not `$data = $xml->xpath($query);`

Comment: Problem is in your second xpath. It's selecting French English etc. For the entire xml document and not for the selected element with id 333. Like @smarber said. Perform the query on $result.

Comment: Also Xpath is doing its job in regard to your title. This is a case where the error is between the display and the back of the chair 

Comment: all done as commanded, still the same Rubbish !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong in my xpath xpression ?

One mistake I could spot is that (common when users ask here on Stackoverflow under the PHP tag for xpath) you're not aware of the xpath injection that is possible in your script.

Therefore for the PHP example I'll be given I will make it safe for that, the function used is taken from [Mitigating XPath Injection Attacks in PHP](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/) which also has more information on the topic.

Next to that (common) mistake, what springs into view directly is that you do many things here while you could just express it with a single XPath expression.

You want the first element which has the ID attribute of a certain value that then contains a child element which contains at least three children elements of which three of them must contain one out of three texts.

For an exmplary ID of 333 and three exemplary texts "English", "French" and "Chinese" the XPath query looks like:

```
(
    //*[@ID=333]
        /*[ count(*) > 2
            and (
                *[contains(., 'English')]
                and *[contains(., 'French')]
                and *[contains(., 'Chinese')]
            )
        ]
    /..
)[1]
```

As you can see, there is not much meaning to wrap more PHP code around it.

Next to these most visible points, it should be noted that the infos are better as an array with three values than three numbered variables (`$infos = ["English", "French", "Chinese"];`).

Example:

```
$expr = sprintf("
    (
        //*[@ID=%d]
            /*[ count(*) > 2
                and (
                    *[contains(., %s)]
                    and *[contains(., %s)]
                    and *[contains(., %s)]
                )
            ]
        /..
    )[1]",
    $parentId, xpath_string($infos[0]), xpath_string($infos[1]), xpath_string($infos[2])
);

list($element) = $xml->xpath($expr) + [NULL];
if (empty($element)) {
    // element not found
    return;
}

// extend element
foreach ($record as $nodname => $val) {
    $element->addChild($nodname, $val);
}
```

This gives the expected result:

```
<Article ID="333">
        <author>John Silas</author>
        <pubDate>01/01/2017</pubDate>
        <Translations>
            <lang1>English</lang1>
            <lang2>French</lang2>
            <lang3>Arab</lang3>
            <lang3>Chinese</lang3>
        </Translations>
    <syntax>irrelevant</syntax><adjectives>None</adjectives><verbs>2</verbs><prepositions>5</prepositions></Article>
```

Comment: a million thanks @hakre. though i deviced another approach to solve the problem, but i love ur style. it worked flawlessly. thank u once more.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie: Feel free to upvote the answer in case you like it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up - and thanks for your feedback!

Comment: nothing much, the only solution i adopted was to convert my xml into an array, as i can easily manipulate the nodes when in array format. thanks @hakre, though your method worked also .